# how to inset text of an array as innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

```
let arr=[<b>hari</b>,<b>gc</b>]
let newarr=arr.join(" ")
let textnode=document.createTextNode(newarr)
let al = document.getElementById("neww");
$(textnode).insertBefore(al);
```

expected output:
**hari gc**

what i get as the output:

```
<b>hari</b> <b>gc</b>
```

I tried using parse from npm HTML react parse..but it results in an error

plese help..

Comment: The active word in textNode is `text`

Answer (score 1):

You can write it via dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yourHtmlString }} />
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = ['<b>hari</b>', '<b>gc</b>']
    let newarr = arr.join(" ")
    let block = document.querySelector(".block");
    block.innerHTML = newarr
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```